Can I Use a Recommendation Letter from a Professor Without an Academic Email?
I have taken two courses with a professor and received perfect grades in both. I believe they can provide a strong recommendation letter for my applications. However, my professor does not have an academic email address.
Can I still request a general recommendation letter from them that I can use for multiple university applications? Would such a letter be acceptable if it’s written on official letterhead or includes their professional details, even though it comes from a personal email address?
I’d appreciate any advice on how to proceed in this situation. Thank you!

It seems odd that they don't have an institutional account; but then, it may just be personal preference not to use it. their choice. If that's the case - and they've presumably provided references before - then a letter on official paper (perhaps stamped?) would almost certainly be OK. I'm not sure about just an email though - although I assume they could cc the HoD and HR.

Is it that they don’t have such an address or rather that they merely don’t use the one they have? In the former case this would suggest they aren’t affiliated with an institution in the first place, which is likely to be a bigger problem than just the lack of official address.

Some schools shut down the email addresses of adjunct faculty any time their contract is inactive.  This can mean that adjunct faculty cannot send/receive institutional email during semesters they are not teaching (nor during the summer).

I doubt that the email address of the letter writer matters, as long as the letter itself clearly identifies the university context where the writer knew you and the writer's status at that time.
If the letters are submitted through an online portal (common these days) the school may never use or even see the writer's email address.
(I am retired, and regularly use my gmail account for academic business, even though I still have access to my university account.)
